# Pipeline chart control

Tags: charts, pipeline

I'm looking for a chart control that is able to display data like this:

[image]

But it must not be Silverlight, Flash or other technology forcing user to install plugin.

It would be best it the control could use HTML5, JavaScript, C#

Answer (score 0):

For me it looks like a simple table with data. You can always later on dynamically render the images on the column 1 and 2 with C# using System.Drawing. Using a charting control for drawing 2 simple images sounds like an overkill while with C# you can easily do what you need and present it to client using the web standards with no plugins.

To overlay 2 images and write some text on it:

```
string graphPath = Server.MapPath("graph.png");
string iconPath = Server.MapPath("icon.png");

// Prepare the template image
System.Drawing.Image template = Bitmap.FromFile(graphPath);
Graphics gfx = Graphics.FromImage(template);

// Draw an icon on it on x=70, y=70 
Bitmap icon = new Bitmap(iconPath);
gfx.DrawImage(icon, new Point(70, 70));

// Draw a string on it on x=150, y=150
Font font = new Font("Arial", 12.0f);
gfx.DrawString("11/14/2009", font, Brushes.Black, new Point(150, 150));

// Output the resulting image
Response.ContentType = "image/png";
template.Save(Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Png);
```

See, you end up coding very little and you don't surrender yourself playing by the rules dictated by a charting control.